# Warning when I take a photo with an iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, photo

When I take a photo with my iPad, the following message appears on the console:

> Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates.

This is my code to take a photo and save it:

```
- (IBAction)selectPhoto:(id)sender {
UIAlertController * alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
UIAlertAction* camera = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Take Photo" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                               handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                         {
                             _imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
                             _imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;
                             _imagePickerController.delegate = self;


                             if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
                                 [_imagePickerController setSourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];

                                 _imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen;
                                 [self presentViewController:_imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
                             }
                             else {
                                 UIAlertController * alert= [UIAlertController
                                                             alertControllerWithTitle:@"Camera not detected"
                                                             message:@""
                                                             preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

                                 UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction
                                                      actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                                      style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                      handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                                      {

                                                      }];
                                 [alert addAction:ok];
                                 [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
                             }
                         }];
[alertController addAction:camera];
[alertController.view layoutIfNeeded];

UIPopoverPresentationController *pop = alertController.popoverPresentationController;
alertController.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = self.button.frame;
alertController.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
pop.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
pop.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil]; 
}
```

And get the new image:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.image"]){
    _img = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    [_button setBackgroundImage:_img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}


[self.imagePickerController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Warning appears when I click in Take photo.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps:

## pragma mark- UIImagePickerController Delegate

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *yourImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: This is practically the same as I have in my code. Don't work for me.